# Can present continuous (passive form) be used with future adverb of time?

Tags: passive-voice, future-tense, present-continuous

Well, I was going through Cambridge Essential Grammar in Use book and in unit 22 I came across this sentence:

Football matches are often played at the weekend, but **no matches are being played next weekend.**

Ok, so does it mean that present continuous (passive form) can be used as future tense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [present continuous](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous-future-arrangements/) is often used to discuss future events. Usually it signifies that the event has been decided beforehand and planned for, as opposed to being a decision you've made just now.

Comment: (also, if it's in a Cambridge book, there's a good chance it's legit :))